# "namely" vs. "in particular"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "namely" and "in particular" in the following? Is one better?

> The equation has a unique solution. Namely, it is the straight line between A and B.
>
> The equation has a unique solution. In particular, it is the straight line between A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both are bad.

---

According to my dictionary(Genius English-Japanese Grand Dictionary),

"Namely" is inserted for an explanation of something, more concrete than "that is to say".

And

"namely" is not used at the first place of a sentence.

**For example:**

the youngest girl,namely Mary.

Three students were mentioned,namely John, Sarah and Sylvia.

**In your example, "namely" is used at the first place of a sentence.**

---

"In particular" is the antonym of "in general".

When you have selections to do something, you chose one of them.

**For example:**

This particular book.
(It is the only book that I can achieve my purpose.There are many books in the world)

"Do you have anything to do?" "Nothing in particular"

particular = particularis(latin language) particle + ar(means like in latin language)

The equation has a unique solution.

The sentence says  "Only one solution" at the first time,clearly.

**I think that "in particular" is not used  in the next sentence,
because there is no selection for solutions.**

---

Your sentence will be good if you change the sentence like this.

**The equation has a unique solution, namely, the straight line between A and B.**

On the above reason, "in particular"

**The equation has good solutions. In particular, it is the straight line between A and B.**

If you use like the above, the first sentence is as well as the second sentence.